# mongo-db: Convert string to array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a `mongodb collection` with around 4-5 million `documents`. It have a field with name `"role": "admin"`. What I want to do is to convert all the roles to array i.e `"role": ["admin"]`.

I prefer `not to use forEach` loop. Please help me with this. I am a bit new to mongodb.

`old documents`

```
{
  "role": "admin"
}
{
  "role": "mod"
}
```

to `new documents`

```
{
  "role": ["admin"]
}
{
  "role": ["mod"]
}
```

Comment: Refer to this link->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401394/mongodb-type-change-to-array

Comment: Yah, saw that post earlier but dont want to use db.eval as it will lock down the db till that completes itself

Comment: I don't think we can do this without using forEach. Why do you prefer not to you use forEach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this using aggregation like this (directly from shell) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
     _id: "$_id",
     role: {$push: "$role"}
    }
  },
   {$out: "newCollection"}
])
```

the $group stage will generate these results:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874a728cf097894d781d7f0"), "role" : [ "mod" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5874a724cf097894d781d7ef"), "role" : [ "admin" ] }
```

and the $out will write it to a specific collection ( can be a new collection or your existing one).

Be carefull when overwritting an existing collection with $out as you can't undo the operation

Comment: Yah your way is the way I want, but i have many additional fields too along with role, it aint working for that. Can u help by modifying a bit?

Comment: @iamsaksham sure, if you want to keep the other fields, just add them in the $group stage like this : "fieldname": { $first: "$fieldname"}