# Mongo insert/update - One to Many Model

Tags: mongodb

I'm just starting learning mongodb and starting personal app for own business.

I'll explain here my problem because I can't solve it myself and I try many ways.

I create one object like this:

```
db.morosos.insert({
"idlor": "XXXXX",
"comunidad": "XXXXX",
"vivienda": "XXXXX",
"demandado": "XXXXX",
"importe": "XXXXX",
"datos": [
    {
        "fecha": "XXXXXX",
        "dato": "XXXXXX"
    }],
"date": new Date("<dd-mm-YYYY>")})
```

Then I want to add new "datos" with new "fecha" and new "dato" like an array.

I try to use:

```
db.morosos.updateOne(
  { "idlor" : "XXXXX" },
  { $inc: { "datos" : { "fecha": "XXXXX", "dato": "XXXX" } } }   )

 db.morosos.updateOne(
  { "idlor" : "XXX" },
  { $push: { "datos" : { "fecha": "XXXXX",
        "dato": "XXXX" } } }   )

db.morosos.update(
   { "idlor" : "XXXX" },
   {
       $addToSet: {
           "datos": {
                "fecha": "XXXXX",
                "dato": "XXXXX" 
                }
           }
       }   )
```

And no ones works like I want, it just change the information or throw me a fail like:

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
            "code" : 16837,
            "errmsg" : "Cannot apply $addToSet to a non-array field. Field named 'datos' has a non-array type Object in the document _id: ObjectId('58c81ba0fb02f3066e2af169')"
    }})
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
            "code" : 16837,
            "errmsg" : "The field 'datos' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: ObjectId('58c81ba0fb02f3066e2af169')}"
    }})
```

So at the moment I don't know what to do, I'm still searching how to solve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: are you sure you're working with mongodb server 3.2 or higher supporting updateOne command?  If not, use the .update() command rather than .updateOne()

```
 db.morosos.updateOne(
  { "idlor" : "XXX" },
  { $push: { "datos" : { "fecha": "XXXXX",
        "dato": "XXXX" } } }   )
```

should work but your update query `{ "idlor" : "XXX" }` doesn't match the sample document.

I changed idlor to match the sample doc (XXX to XXXXX)

```
>  db.morosos.updateOne(
...   { "idlor" : "XXXXX" },
...   { $push: { "datos" : { "fecha": "XXXXX",
...         "dato": "XXXX" } } }   )
```

and the push worked just fine

```
> db.morosos.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c9890a57c5133b63c05b86"),
    "idlor" : "XXXXX",
    "datos" : [
        {
            "fecha" : "XXXXXX",
            "dato" : "XXXXXX"
        },
        {
            "fecha" : "XXXXX",
            "dato" : "XXXX"
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: Thanks for try help but bro, XXX is just and example to don't write the information. Use X as a variable, think here XXX is same than XXXXX.

Comment: you're sure that mongodb server 3.2 or above which has the updateone command?  The exact command seems to work on my 3.2 on ubuntu

Comment: I'm using mLab free server. mongod version: 3.2.11 (MMAPv1)

Comment: 2017-03-15T20:24:29.727+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] WriteError: The field 'datos' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: ObjectId('58c81ba0fb02f3066e2af169')} :
WriteError({
        "index" : 0,
        "code" : 16837,
        "errmsg" : "The field 'datos' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: ObjectId('58c81ba0fb02f3066e2af169')}",
        "op" : { "q" : {
                        "idlor" : "LOR01/16"
                },
                "u" : {
                        "$push" : {
                                "datos" : {

Comment: "fecha" : "27/07/2016",
                                        "dato" : "Carta enviada"
                                }
                        }
                },
                "multi" : false,
                "upsert" : false
        }
})
WriteError@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:469:48
Bulk/mergeBatchResults@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:836:49
Bulk/executeBatch@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:906:13
Bulk/this.execute@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:1150:21
DBCollection.prototype.updateOne@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:550:17
@(shell):1:1

Comment: the error is telling you that if you were to do a find on { "idlor" : "LOR01/16" }, datos is not a list.  for the sake of argument, can you put the result of findOne({ "idlor" : "LOR01/16" }) in your question.

Comment: {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58c81ba0fb02f3066e2af169"),
        "idlor" : "LOR01/16",
        "comunidad" : "x",
        "vivienda" : "x",
        "demandado" : "x",
        "importe" : "x",
        "datos" : {
                "fecha" : "08/03/2017",
                "dato" : "Pagado Ejecucion"
        },
        "date" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
}

Comment: right, in your case, you can only $push if that "datos" field is already an array.  You'd have to download the document, convert the field to a list, and update the whole document rather than issuing a push command. Here is a question that provides server side script that will go through and convert http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401394/mongodb-type-change-to-array.

Comment: Thanks I add [] on "datos" [{}] on mLab "records/page" that allow you modify and it works now :)