# $push to an array in MongoDB with mongoose doesn't work

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, types, push

> errmsg: 'The field \'weight\' must be an array but is of type int in
>   document

My Schema:

```
weight: [{
  type: Number
}]
```

and my post request:

```
app.post('/edit', function(req, res){
    var update = {  $push: {"weight": req.body.weight}};
    User.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, function (err)
    {
      if (err)
      {
          console.log(err);
      }
      else
      {
          console.log('yep');
      }
    })
});
```

Comment: Looks like your field is something like `{"weight": 3}` in db and you're using `$push` to push array value into `int` type field.

Comment: So, I should change the schema to smth like:     weight: [{
      type: Array
    }], ? it doesn't work

Comment: No, the schema definition is correct. I meant to suggest that you've to fix the data in the `weight` field first. It should look like `{"weight": [3]}` in db and you can use the update with `$push` to add more values into array. So you possibly need like a update script to change the data first. See if this answer help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401394/mongodb-type-change-to-array

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple documents in the collection that match your `conditions`, you can update only suitable one by adding `{ weight: { $type: 4 } }` to your `conditions`.

Otherwise your application's schema doesn't match data in the database.

Comment: I use a user_id as a condition, so I have only one record

Comment: Then it falls into 'otherwise' part of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This might work.

//Schema

```
weight: [Number]
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

//Or this way too if pushing objects into array

//Schema

```
weight: [{
  weight: {
    type: Number
  }
}]
```

//Then in API

```
var update = {  $push: {"weight": { "weight": req.body.weight }}};
```