# change elements array to fields mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, field

I have these documents:

```
{ "Sigle" : [ "RIPGD", "EDRFR" ]}
```

How can I change to this

```
{ "Sigle" : [ {Field_one:"RIPGD"}, {Field_two:"EDRFR"} ]}
```

Comment: `{ "Sigle" : [ Field_one:"RIPGD", Field_two:"EDRFR" ]}` is not a valid JSON

Comment: I corrected the error !!!

Comment: You can follow similar question other way asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401394/mongodb-type-change-to-array